# How to add randomizing colors in my Turtle Graphic - Python

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics

So I have this recursive graphic that works perfectly fine, but I was wondering for turtle graphics, and in my case how do I get each line segment to be a random color?

```
from turtle import *

def line(t, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """draws the line segment from x1,y1 to x2,y2"""

    t.up()
    t.goto(x1, y1)
    t.down()
    t.goto(x2, y2)

def drawLine(t, x1, y1, x2, y2, level):
    """forms the shape"""

    if level == 0:
        line(t, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    else:
        xm = ((x1 + x2) + (y2 - y1)) // 2
        ym = ((y1 + y2) + (x1 - x2)) // 2
        drawLine(t, x1, y1, xm, ym, level-1)
        drawLine(t, xm, ym, x2, y2, level-1)

def main():
    """the main function"""

    myTurtle = Turtle()

    myTurtle.hideturtle()

    num = int(input("Please enter the number of levels: "))

    drawLine(myTurtle, 100, 0, 100, -200, num)


main()
```

Comment: the graphic makes  C shape that loops in the segments depending how many levels you add, but I imagine that's just fluff info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a random color triple using `tuple(randint(0,255) for _ in range(3))` where `randint` is from `random` module. You can then call this function every time you draw a line `t.pencolor(*get_rand_color())`.

PS : `colormode(255)` must be set in the code for setting colors as tuples, now in theory you can get any of the `16.8 million colors` possible.

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint
def line(t, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """draws the line segment from x1,y1 to x2,y2"""

    t.up()
    t.goto(x1, y1)
    t.down()
    t.pencolor(*get_rand_color())
    t.goto(x2, y2)

def get_rand_color():
    """
    Returns a 3-tuple of random numbers in the range 0 - 255
    eg : (89, 103, 108)
    """
    return tuple(randint(0,255) for _ in range(3))


def drawLine(t, x1, y1, x2, y2, level):
    """forms the shape"""
    if level == 0:
        line(t, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    else:
        xm = ((x1 + x2) + (y2 - y1)) // 2
        ym = ((y1 + y2) + (x1 - x2)) // 2
        drawLine(t, x1, y1, xm, ym, level-1)
        drawLine(t, xm, ym, x2, y2, level-1)

def main():
    """the main function"""
    myTurtle = Turtle()
    myTurtle.hideturtle()
    colormode(255)
    num = 6
    drawLine(myTurtle, 100, 0, 100, -200, num)

main()
```

For level `5` this is how it looks like

[image: For level 5 this is how it looks like]

Edit : As @cdlane points out in comments, "`colormode(255)` must be set to specify colors as values in the range 0 - 255. By default, turtle's color mode uses values in the range 0.0 - 1.0 and they can be specified by a tuple: (0.5, 0.125, 0.333)".

In other words if you don't do `colormode(255)`, you can change the `get_rand_color` function to return values in the range `0.0` to `1.0` instead of `0` to `255`.

Comment: Your claim that "colormode(255) must be set in the code for setting colors as tuples" is not true.  It must be set to specify colors as values in the range 0 - 255.  By default, turtle's color mode uses values in the range 0.0 - 1.0 and they can be specified by a tuple: `(0.5, 0.125, 0.333)`

Comment: thank you for pointing it out,, if you dont mind I am adding what you said as an edit @cdlane

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of colors then use `random.choice` to pick a random color from the list when drawing each line.

Here is the code update

```
from turtle import *
import random

colors = ['red','green','blue','indianred','firebrick','ForestGreen'] # color list

def line(t, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    """draws the line segment from x1,y1 to x2,y2"""
    
    t.color(random.choice(colors))  # pick color from list
    t.up()
    t.goto(x1, y1)
    t.down()
    t.goto(x2, y2)

......
```

Output (10 levels)

[image: Colors]

Comment: do you mind if I edit my answer to add a screenshot as well? both our answers are slightly similar so dont want to seem like I copied yours by adding the screenshot :)

Comment: No problem - try a different level to add variety :)

Comment: thanks +1 for the screenshot and for beating me to this

Comment: wow, both these answers clear it all up for me, and I will be testing both methods to see what works best, but thank you again so much !!!!